# How to pass extra parameter in ajax call to php using jQuery DataTables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

How to pass extra parameter in ajax call to php using [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net)?

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable =  $('#student-grid').DataTable( {
                responsive: {
                    details: {
                        renderer: function ( api, rowIdx ) {
                            var data = api.cells( rowIdx, ':hidden' ).eq(0).map( function ( cell ) {
                                var header = $( api.column( cell.column ).header() );
                                return  '<p style="color:#00A">'+header.text()+' : '+api.cell( cell ).data()+'</p>';
                            } ).toArray().join('');

                            return data ?    $('<table/>').append( data ) :    false;
                        }
                    }
                },
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "borrowedBookNew.php" // json datasource
            } );

        } );
```

I want to pass a new parameter to my php file and get a new result.

Comment: This question is very clear and should not be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass additional data by setting the `ajax` parameter to an object:

```
$('#student-grid').dataTable({
    // ...
    ajax: {
        url: 'borrowedBookNew.php',
        data: {
            customField: 'customValue'
        }
    }
});
```

You can also pass `data` a function that receives the current data as an object which you can manipulate. This is especially useful for adding dynamic data that isn't available at page load.

Source: http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to mark the correct answer.

Comment: Should I use this syntax `"data":` or this one `data:`?